# Rewind iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I'm making a game using Libgdx. In my main loop, I use an iterator to iterate through all the elements of my world. My `World` class look like this :

```
public class World implements Iterable<GameElement>
{
    ...
    public Iterator<GameElement> iterator()
    {
        return listGameElements.iterator();
    }
}
```

But when I profile my application, there is a lot of allocations coming from the line `listGameElements.iterator()` (this line is called at every game loop, so a lot of times in a second).

I wanted to put my iterator as an private attribute of my class, but the iterator can be used only one time.
Is there a way to rewind an iterator, to avoid making more allocations?

Comment: How is your iterator created? Is it written by you or from an existing collection? Its surprising that it's such a bottleneck (unless its creating its own collection internally)

Comment: Well in the constructor I add all my game Elements in the ArrayList. Then I call this method to return an iterator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it based on the [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) it allows you to go in both directions.

Example of usage:

```
aList.add("1");
aList.add("2");
aList.add("3");
aList.add("4");
aList.add("5");

ListIterator listIterator = aList.listIterator();

System.out.println("moving forward");
while(listIterator.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(listIterator.next());
}

System.out.println("moving backward");
while(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
  System.out.println(listIterator.previous());
}
```